# How to stop background color gradient from repeating itself? (css)

Tags: html, css, background

I don't really get how to fix that a background-gradient doesn't repeat itself. I did a lot of research but most of the things don't help. I really need it since it's for my thesis, so I'd really appreciate the help. Thanks on advance.

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fjalla+One);

body, html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
}

body{
    font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
    background: #2C3E50;  /* fallback for old browsers */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to top, #4CA1AF, #2C3E50);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #4CA1AF, #2C3E50); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
  }

#GridView1{
    border-radius: 10px;
}

  h1{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 60px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    text-shadow: #533d4a 1px 1px, #533d4a 2px 2px, #533d4a 3px 3px, #533d4a 4px 4px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 60px;
  }

   .icon-div {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px;
  }


.icon {
    display: inline;
    -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
    transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px transparent;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition-property: box-shadow, transform;
    transition-property: box-shadow, transform;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 35px;
    width: 170px;
    height: 170px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

#animatie1.icon {
    position: relative;
    animation-name: animatieboven;
    animation-duration: 1s;
}

@keyframes animatieboven {
    0% {
        top: -20px;
    }

    100% {
        top: 0px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div style="text-align: center;">
          <div align="center" class="icon-div" id="Afspraken" style="display: inline-block;">
            <a href="../Menu/indexmenu.aspx">
              <img src="https://www.icloud.com/system/cloudos/17BHotfix5/cloudos_foundation/17BHotfix5/en-us/source/resources/images/app_icons/fmf_icon@2x.png" id="animatie1" class="icon"/>
            </a>
              <h1 style="text-align: center; color:white;">Situaties</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by repeat-itself?

Answer (score 0):

Use the css property `background-repeat: no-repeat;`.

You can see more info here -> [Background-repeat](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-repeat.asp)